# how to Extract function information from C++ dll?

Tags: c++, function, dll

I'm writing a c++ project，the function of my project is extracting a function name from a c++ dll. I know there are some tools，but I want to implement it in my c++ project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract function information from c++ dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021064/extract-function-information-from-c-dll). Also, "Does anyone know how to implement it?" is not a valid question here; a perfectly correct answer would be "Yes, someone knows how to do it." or "No, no one knows how to do it.", or "Probably there's someone somewhere who knows how to do it.", none of which would be helpful. Please take a moment or two to visit the [help], which has tips on how to ask questions here to get better answers. Good luck.

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Note that a DLL is binary, whether it was generated using C, C++, C#... Look for the COFF format and will tell you everything there is to know. Microsoft provides a file that describes every single COFF structures.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx

You have to agree with the Microsoft license. That document will give you all the information about the DLL (and EXE) files.

Make sure to read the file in Binary mode (i.e. with the ios::binary or with fopen() using the "b" flag.)